# Overloading insertion >> operator?

Tags: c++, input, struct

I just started looking at structs in C++ and thought I might try and figure out how to overload the stream insertion operator to take and object of *Line* (which itself contains objects of *Point*). I think I need some sort of declaration of overloading in Line? and possibly point? I found some similiar questions but to be honest I can't figure it out at all.

It's a very simple program so hopefully someone could take the time to look at it and explain to me how I should be going about it?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;

//define Point & Line type
struct Point{
    float x, y;
};
struct Line{
    Point p1, p2;
    istream& operator>>( istream& in, const Line& line); //something like this here?
};
//function declarations
Point calcMidpoint(const Line& rline);

//operator overload
istream& operator>>( istream& in, const Line& line){
    in >> line.p1.x >> line.p1.y >> line.p2.x >> line.p2.y;
    return in;
}

//MAIN
int main(){
    Line line;
    cout << "please enter one pair of x and y values followed by another like so (x1 y1 x2 y2): ";
    cin >> line;
    //get midpoint of line
    Point mp;
    mp = returnMidpoint(line);
    cout << "The Midpoint is.. (" << mp.x << " " << mp.y << ")" <<endl;

    return 0;
}

//can be used in a large expression at the expence of creating temp instances
Point calcMidpoint(const Line& rline){
    Point midpoint;
    midpoint.x = (rline.p2.x + rline.p1.x) / 2;
    midpoint.y = (rline.p2.y + rline.p1.y) / 2;
    return midpoint;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binary operators can only be defined as member functions if the **first** operand is of the type of the class. Since this isn't the case (the first operand is `std::istream&`), you must define a *free* function:

```
class Foo;

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Foo & x)
{
  //...
  return is;
}
```

It might be useful to declare this function a `friend` inside your class so it can access private members.

Comment: i'm not familiar with the term free function, im currently googling for more info but mostly getting results on free() instead so if you fancy telling me a little more thatd be great :) also i just have the one cpp file with a couple of structs inside, at the moment in not really familiar with classes. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @holly: He just meant a normal functions that is not a method from some class.

Comment: @Holly: A free function is a function that is not a member-function. That means it is declared outside of a class.

Comment: free function is short hand for "Free Standing Function" ie it is not a member of some other entity but stands alone. ie a normal function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your `operator>>` as a free function. Apart from that, the code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, unfortunately i'm not familiar with the term free function, im currently googling for more info but mostly getting results on free() instead ha, in you could link me to a resource or tell me a bit more about what that means it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload the `>>` operator for input *as a member function* because your `Line` and `Point` are on the right side of the operator. Definitely a silly reason, but it is just the nature of the syntax.

When you get to classes, this is more important because your variables, such as `p1.x`, are going to be `private` and you won't be able to put them directly in.

Also, your `const Line& line` should not be `const`, because you are changing it by inputting into its variables!